# Issue during spring batch upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to upgrade spring batch version 5.X with spring boot 3.0.2 and java 17 from spring boot version 2.7.3

I have a default batch config class and a custom job config class(ActivateTestJob).
DefaultBatchJobConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class DefaultBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    
     @Override
        protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factoryBean.setDatabaseType("databse");
            factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_DEFAULT");
            factoryBean.setTablePrefix("Test");
            factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factoryBean.getObject();
        }
}
```

ActivateTestJob.java

```
@Configuration
public class ActivateTestJob{

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public JobExecutionListener activeTestListener() {
        return new ActivatedTestProcessListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public ActivatedTestTasklet activateTEstTasklet() {
        return new ActivatedTestTasklet();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job activatedTestJob() {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("activatedTestJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(activeTestListener()).start(activatedTestStep()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step activatedTestStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("activatedProgramStep")
                      .tasklet(activateProgramTasklet()).build();
    }
}
```

After upgrading the srping boot vesion I found

1. DefaultBatchConfigurer class has been removed and therefore i cannot override createJobRepository() method to create JobRepository.
2. StepBuilderFactory and JobBuilderFactory classes are depricated.

I am following spring batch [migration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide) guide.
For Default batch config i modified the code as below to support spring -batch 5.x.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class DefaultBatchConfig {

    @Bean
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDatabaseType("database");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_DEFAULT");
        factoryBean.setTablePrefix("Test");
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```

I am not sure fully if above changes are correct.
For ActivateTestJob, i am not sure how can i replace stepBuilderFactory and Jobbuilderfactory.

Comment: Hia, could you clarify the problem you're having now. The 'I am not sure fully if above changes are correct" means that we can not neither. But looking at the configuration it looks like you could just provide this implicit case classes by using a bit different, but more explicit approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring Batch 5, you don't need to implement `BatchConfigurer` to customize infrastructure beans. The `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation now provides attributes for common parameters (tablePrefix, charset, etc). In your case, the equivalent configuration would be something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(tablePrefix="Test", isolationLevelForCreate="ISOLATION_DEFAULT")
public class DefaultBatchConfig {

}
```

By default, Spring Batch will inspect the application context for a data source (default bean name `dataSource`) and a transaction manager (default bean name `transactionManager`) and use them to configure the job repository. Those could be the ones auto-configured by Spring Boot. If you use custom beans, you can specify them using the annotation's attributes `dataSourceRef` and `transactionManagerRef` respectively. Please refer to the javadoc of [@EnableBatchPocessing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html) for more details.

> For ActivateTestJob, i am not sure how can i replace stepBuilderFactory and Jobbuilderfactory.

This is explained with code examples in the migration guide you shared here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#jobbuilderfactory-and-stepbuilderfactory-bean-exposureconfiguration

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i love your work on spring-batch. 
I have one doubt how can i set database type in new spring batch configuration. 
```
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDatabaseType("oracle");
```

Comment: Thank you! I see there is no way to specify the `databaseType` through the annotation, so we need to add that to Spring Batch. I created a feature request for that: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4320.